# no module named blog.eg found django

Tags: python, django

I'm facing this error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked      
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed    
File "C:\Users\user\demoDjango\blog\eg\urls.py", line 1, in <module>
from blog.eg.views import home
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog.eg'
```

below is my djangoDemo/blog/eg/urls file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns =[
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
]
```

And here is my eg/views file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, Django! ")
```

And finally demodjango/blog/urls mapping file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
        path("", include("eg.urls")) ,
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried to add your APP in the INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py ?

In your settings file you will have something like

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    '<YOUR_APP_HERE>',
]
```

Comment: Yes l  added in my installed  apps: